# Does the query have to be this form?

Tags: sql

book name : Database System Concept / author : Silberschatz, Korth, Sudarshan

problem : Find the total number of (distinct) students who have taken course sections taught by the instructor with ID 10101

answer :

```
select count(distinct ID)
from takes 
where (course_id, sec_id, semester, year) in
          (select course_id, sec_id, semester, year
           from teaches 
           where teaches.ID = 10101
          );
```

my query :

```
select count (distinct ID)
from takes 
where course_id in (SELECT course_id from teaches where teaches.ID = 10101);
```

Do I have to be a correct answer?

Comment: Your version answers questions about courses, but not about sections.

Comment: @GordonLinoff oh.. very very thank you :)